# Jackson mapper with generic class in scala

Tags: json, scala, serialization, jackson, case-class

I am trying to serialise `GeneralResponse`:

```
case class GeneralResponse[T](succeeded: Boolean, payload: Option[T])
```

and the payload is `GroupsForUserResult`:

```
case class GroupsForUserResult(groups: Seq[UUID]).
```

I am using `mapper.readValue(response.body, classOf[GeneralResponse[GroupsForUserResult]])` but unfortunately the payload is serialised as a `Map` and not as the desired case class (`GroupForUserResult`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because of Java Erasure - Jackson can't know at runtime about the generic type T from the line -

```
mapper.readValue(response.body, classOf[GeneralResponse[GroupsForUserResult]])
```

A solution to this problem will be

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.`type`.TypeReference

mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference[GeneralResponse[GroupsForUserResult]] {})
```

This way you provide an instance of `TypeReference` with all the needed Type information.

Comment: It doesn't work in my case. Having `case class InputMessage[+S<:Storage,+P<:Partitioning](fromView: View[S,P], toView: View[S,P], partition: Partition)`  and `ObjMapper.readValue[InputMessage[S3Storage, TimePartitioning]](inputMsg, new TypeReference[InputMessage[S3Storage, TimePartitioning]]() {})` and I'm still getting the error

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is close enough but you also have to provide the Type Parameter to `.readValue` method,

**Working example with test,**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.`type`.TypeReference
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import org.scalatest.{FunSuite, Matchers}

case class Customer[T](name: String, address: String, metadata: T)

case class Privileged(desc: String)

class ObjectMapperSpecs extends FunSuite with Matchers {

  test("deserialises to case class") {

    val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
      .registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

    val value1 = new TypeReference[Customer[Privileged]] {}

    val response = objectMapper.readValue[Customer[Privileged]](
      """{
           "name": "prayagupd",
           "address": "myaddress",
           "metadata": { "desc" : "some description" }
         }
      """.stripMargin, new TypeReference[Customer[Privileged]] {})

    response.metadata.getClass shouldBe classOf[Privileged]
    response.metadata.desc shouldBe "some description"
  }

}
```

The signature of [`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper#readValue`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.java#L2944),

```
public <T> T readValue(String content, TypeReference valueTypeRef)
    throws IOException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException
{
    return (T) _readMapAndClose(_jsonFactory.createParser(content), _typeFactory.constructType(valueTypeRef));
}
```

If you don't provide the type parameter, it will blow up with error `Customer cannot be cast to scala.runtime.Nothing$`