# Deserializing generic list of objects to the right type with Jackson

Tags: json, scala, jackson, jackson-module-scala

My json string has an array at the top level. E.g.:

```
[
  {...},
  {...}
]
```

And I'm using jackson to deserialize it like so:

```
val parser = mapper.getFactory.createParser(json)
val mylist = mapper.readValue(parser, classOf[List[Track]])
```

The trouble is that the values of the list are coming out as `HashMap` rather than `Track` objects, even though I'm specifying that this is a generic list of `Track`s. On the console:

```
mylist.isInstanceOf[List[Track]]
> true
mylist.head.isInstanceOf[Track]
> false
mylist.head.isInstanceOf[HashMap]
> true
```

**How can I do to make sure jackson returns Track objects instead of HashMap?**

Comment: Dont know scala, but generics don't have type info at runtime, so you probalby need to use TypeReference<List<Track>> http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html

Comment: This worked, thanks! `mapper.readValue[List[Track]](json, new TypeReference[List[Track]]() { })`

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29806620/jackson-mapper-with-generic-class-in-scala